# Testing Methods within Vue Components using Jasmine

Tags: vue.js, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have the following test which works great

```
  it('does not render chapter div or error div', () => {
        const payLoad =  chapter;
        const switcher = 'guild';
        var vm = getComponent(payLoad, switcher).$mount();
        expect(vm.$el.querySelector('#chapter-card')).toBeNull();
        expect(vm.$el.querySelector('#error-card')).toBeNull();

    });
```

To do this I wrote a helper method that mounts a component:

```
  const getComponent = (prop1) => {
        let vm = new Vue({
            template: '<div><compd :payLoad="group" :index="index" "></compd ></div></div>',
            components: {
                compd,
            },
            data: {
                payLoad: prop1,
                
            },

        })
        return vm;
    }
```

however, I have a method within my vue component compd. For simplicitys sake, lets call it

```
add(num,num){
return num+num;
}
```

I want to be able to write a test case similar to the following:

```
  it('checks the add method works', () => {
       
        expect(compd.add(1,2).toBe(3));

    });
```

I cannot figure out how to do this. Has anyone any suggestions?
The documentation here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html
Does not cover testing methods.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis after `expect(compd.add(1,2)`

Comment: It should be `expect(compd.add(1,2)).toBe(3)`

Answer (score 2):

Source code from [vue repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/test/unit/features/options/methods.spec.js)

As you can see the method gets called simply on the instance

```
const vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    a: 1
  },
  methods: {
    plus () {
      this.a++
    }
  }
})
vm.plus()
expect(vm.a).toBe(2)
```

You can also access the method via `$options` like in this case ([vue source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/test/unit/features/instance/properties.spec.js))

```
const A = Vue.extend({
  methods: {
    a () {}
  }
})
const vm = new A({
  methods: {
    b () {}
  }
})
expect(typeof vm.$options.methods.a).toBe('function')
```

Update:
To test child components use `$children` to access the necessary child. Example

```
var childToTest = vm.$children.find((comp)=>comp.$options.name === 'accordion')`  assuming name is set to `accordion`
```

After that you can

```
childToTest.plus();
vm.$nextTick(()=>{
  expect(childToTest.someData).toBe(someValue)
  done(); //call test done callback here
})
```

If you have a single child component and not a v-for put a `ref` on it
`

```
vm.$refs.mycomponent.myMethod()
```